# How to know if one shared library depends on another shared library or not?

Tags: c++, linux, gcc, linker, shared-libraries

I wrote a shared library named "libmyssl.so", I use some openssl function in my code, the make file looks like follows:

> g++ -v -shared -lz -lssl -lcrypto -Wl,-soname,libmyssl.so.1,-o
>   libmyssl.so.1.0 myssl.o

After that, I use **ldd** command to look if it depends on **libssl.so**:

> ldd libmyssl.so.1.0

The result as follows:

```
linux-vdso.so.1 =>  (0x00007fff743fe000) 
libstdc++.so.6 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libstdc++.so.6 (0x00007f0bc963b000) 
libc.so.6 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6 (0x00007f0bc9276000) 
libm.so.6 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libm.so.6 (0x00007f0bc8f6f000) 
/lib64/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2 (0x00007f0bc9ea0000) 
libgcc_s.so.1 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libgcc_s.so.1 (0x00007f0bc8d59000)
```

It seems it didn't depend on **libssl.so**, am I right?

However, I use **readelf -s** command to see the symbols as follows:

> readelf -s libmyssl.so.1.0

The reasult as follow:

```
......
259: 0000000000000000     0 NOTYPE  GLOBAL DEFAULT  UND SSL_new
260: 0000000000000000     0 NOTYPE  GLOBAL DEFAULT  UND SSL_get_shutdown
261: 0000000000000000     0 FUNC    GLOBAL DEFAULT  UND close@GLIBC_2.2.5 (4)
262: 0000000000000000     0 NOTYPE  GLOBAL DEFAULT  UND d2i_X509
263: 0000000000000000     0 NOTYPE  GLOBAL DEFAULT  UND X509_get_pubkey
264: 0000000000000000     0 NOTYPE  GLOBAL DEFAULT  UND SSL_set_info_callback
265: 0000000000000000     0 FUNC    GLOBAL DEFAULT  UND gmtime_r@GLIBC_2.2.5 (4)
......
```

It seems that the **X509_get_putkey** is not relocated. So it should depend on **libssl.so**. Maybe I didn't understand it well.

Hope someone can explain more about that, thanks very much!

Comment: A better way to check is would be to use `objdump` and looked for needed libraries as `objdump -p libmyssl.so.1.0 | grep NEEDED`

Comment: I try you command and get the same result - only libstdc++.so.6 and libc.so.6 in the list, libssl.so dosen't appear.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Some distributions would require you to list linked libraries after object files that reference them (to mimic how static libs work). So try to build like:

```
g++ -v -shared -Wl,-soname,libmyssl.so.1,-o libmyssl.so.1.0 myssl.o -lz -lssl -lcrypto
```

Comment: Thanks very much! You are right. I move the -lz -lssl -lcrypto to the end of the command line, after that, I found the result of "ldd libmyssl.so.1.0" contains "libssl.so".  I try to remove "-lssl" from the command line, It still can build "myssl.so.1.0" successfully. So I want to know if I can remove all depends libraries when building a shared library?

Comment: By default ld does not require to resolve missing symbols in shared library so it won't emit an error if you remove -lssl. You'll get an error at runtime though (loader won't know that it needs to load libssl and you'll get undefined symbol for SSL_new). I recommend to link with `-Wl,--no-undefined` to catch such errors at build time.

Comment: Understand.Thanks for your explanation.