# Creating a shared object which depends on other shared objects

Tags: c++, linux, opencv, gcc, shared-libraries

#### The Problem

I am creating a shared object (called `libA.so`) which uses OpenCV shared objects (for example `libopencv_core.so`).

Here's my shared object's code:

```
#include "opencv2/opencv.hpp"
#include "rgbframe.h"

#define API_EXPORT  __attribute__ ((visibility ("default")))
#define API_LOCAL  __attribute__ ((visibility ("hidden")))

using namespace cv;

API_EXPORT RGBFrame getFrame(int width, int height){
    VideoCapture cap(0);
    RGBFrame frame;
    
    if(!cap.isOpened())
        return frame;

    // Set camera resolution
    cap.set(CV_CAP_PROP_FRAME_WIDTH, width);
    cap.set(CV_CAP_PROP_FRAME_HEIGHT, height);
    
    frame.rows = height;
    frame.cols = width;
    frame.data = new uchar[frame.rows * frame.cols * 3];
    Mat mat(frame.rows, frame.cols, CV_8UC3, frame.data);
    
    // Get a frame
    cap >> mat;
    
    // Convert BGR to RGB
    cv::cvtColor(mat, mat, CV_BGR2RGB, 3);
    
    return frame;
}
```

Also here's how I compile it:

```
gcc -shared -fPIC -Wl,-soname,libA.so -std=c++11 -lpthread -lopencv_core -lopencv_video -lopencv_highgui -lopencv_imgproc -o libA.so test.cpp
```

Therefore from the line above, we know that `libA.so` depends on `opencv_core`, `opencv_video` and so forth.

It compiles and links fine, but when I `ldd libA.so`, it prints:

```
linux-vdso.so.1 =>  (0x00007ffc71b76000)
libgcc_s.so.1 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libgcc_s.so.1 (0x00007f074cbaa000)
libc.so.6 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6 (0x00007f074c7e3000)
/lib64/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2 (0x000055b29e8bd000)
```

meaning that my library doesn't depend on OpenCV `.so` files. Apart from this, when I use my library in a simple program, the whole program won't compile. There will be a bunch of `undefined reference` to OpenCV functions I have used in `libA.so`.

#### The Question

How should I build my `libA.so` such that it depends on OpenCV libraries? and when I use it in other programs, it will be compiled and linked fine.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is probably a dup of [how-to-know-if-one-shared-library-depends-on-another-shared-library-or-not](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40739799/how-to-know-if-one-shared-library-depends-on-another-shared-library-or-not)

TLDR is that you should put linked libs after object/source files.