# C: Handle undefined symbols in shared object

Tags: c, gcc, dlopen, undefined-symbol

I've struggled with `dlopen` and *undefined symbols*.

What I have and tried so far:

**libraryA.a** with function `functionA()`

**libraryA.so** with function `functionA()`

**libraryB.so** which is using `functionA()`

an executable which loads **libraryB.so** with dlopen.

What I got is:

```
undefined symbol: functionA
```

How I build:

libraryA:

```
gcc -std=gnu11 -O2 -g -Wall -Wstack-usage=2000 -Werror
-fdiagnostics-color -fPIC -pipe -fsigned-char -fno-asynchronous-unwind-tables      
-fno-stack-protector -I../include/ libraryA.c -shared -o libraryA.so
```

libraryB:

```
gcc -std=gnu11 -O2 -g -Wall -Wstack-usage=2000 -Werror -fdiagnostics-color 
-fPIC -pipe -fsigned-char -fno-asynchronous-unwind-tables 
-fno-stack-protector -I../include/ libraryB.c -shared -o libraryB.so
```

Build executable:

```
-std=gnu99 -pipe -fno-strict-aliasing -fsigned-char -fno-asynchronous-unwind-tables
-fno-stack-protector -Wall -Wextra -Wundef -Wno-sign-compare -Wno-unused-parameter
-Wno-packed-bitfield-compat -Wno-misleading-indentation -fomit-frame-pointer
-maccumulate-outgoing-args -fPIC -m64 -g3 -gdwarf-2 -fno-common -Wstrict-prototypes
-Wimplicit -Wno-pointer-sign -c executable.c -o executable libraryA.a
```

Open libraryB in executable like this here:

```
void *handle = dlopen("libraryB.so", RTLD_LAZY);

if (handle == NULL) {
    fprintf( stderr, "Load error (%s)!\n", dlerror());
    return NULL;
}
```

How can I fix this behavior? I also tried the flag **-rdynamic** without success. I also tried different dlopen flags but also without success.

Can anyone please help me?

Answer (score 1):

You need to link `libraryB.so` with `libraryA.so` since `libraryB.so` uses a symbol from `libraryA.so`.

Just add `libraryA.so` to `libraryB.so`'s link command.

Depending on where the libraries are installed you may also need to use the `-rpath` flag.

Also, since `libraryB.so` is dependent on `libraryA.so`, your `Makefile` rules should explicitly specify this dependency.

Comment: This I also tried with the **-L** and **-l** option, but I still have the undefined symbol in **libraryB**

Comment: Still unresolved.
    `gcc -std=gnu11 -O2 -g -Wall -Wstack-usage=2000 -Werror
    -fdiagnostics-color
    -fPIC -pipe -fsigned-char -fno-asynchronous-unwind-tables
    -fno-stack-protector -I../include/ libraryA.so libraryB.c -shared -o libraryB.so`

Comment: 1) Use `objdump -T` to verify that the symbol referenced from libraryB.so is identical to the symbol declared in libraryA.so, and the libraryA.so symbol is declared as global 2) Use `objdump -x` to verify that `libraryb.so` specifies "NEEDED libraryA.so`

Comment: 1) 
libraryA.so

`00000000001d7d3b g    DF .text 000000000000008d  Base        functionA`

libraryB.so

`0000000000000000      DF *UND* 0000000000000000              functionA`

2) libraryB.so show no specified libraryA.so

Do I something wrong?

Comment: Try putting libraryA.so _after_ libraryB.c (see [creating-a-shared-object-which-depends-on-other-shared-objects](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40780247/creating-a-shared-object-which-depends-on-other-shared-objects) for background).

Comment: I've tried this out but the functionA() is still unresolved.
`gcc -std=gnu11 -O2 -g -Wall -Wstack-usage=2000 -Werror -fdiagnostics-color -fPIC -pipe -fsigned-char -fno-asynchronous-unwind-tables -fno-stack-protector -I../include/ libraryB.c libraryA.so -shared -o libraryB.so `

nm -g libraryB() `U functionA()`

Answer (score 0):

When you build Library B, you need to link it against Library A:

```sh
gcc -shared -o libraryB.so libraryB.c -lraryA
```

You might need to add a suitable `-L` option if `libraryA.so` isn't already on your search path.

If Library B is intended to be *complete*, with no undefined symbols, add the option `-Wl,--no-undefined` to your link line.  That way, any missing dependencies will be reported at link time, rather than waiting until run-time.

Otherwise, you may still examine `libarryB.so` with `ldd` to see which libraries it references.

Answer (score -1):

**Solution**

```
gcc -std=gnu11 -O2 -g -Wall -Wstack-usage=2000 -Werror -fdiagnostics-color -fPIC -pipe -fsigned-char -fno-asynchronous-unwind-tables -fno-stack-protector -I../include/ libraryB.c libraryA_static.a -shared -o libraryB.so
```

I build my libraryB with the static library of A and after that everything is fine and I can use all symbols and functions.

Many thanks to all of you!

Comment: That's not the same, though - you've now linked B *statically* against A.  You should be able to link B *dynamically* against A so they can be updated independently.  Something like `gcc -shared -o libraryB.so libraryB.c -lraryA`.  Add `-Wl,--no-undefined` if you want to be sure that all of B's requirements are satisfied.