# g++ undefined reference with a shared library

Tags: c++, g++, shared-libraries

I'm trying to compile a file with a shared library using the following command:

```
g++ -L. -lsubmit main.cpp
```

It outputs:

```
/tmp/ccRFpx1v.o: In function `main':
main.cpp:(.text+0x5): undefined reference to `Submit_test()'
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
```

I have main.cpp and libsubmit.so in working directory. Here's my main.cpp

```
void Submit_test();
int main()
{
    Submit_test();
}
```

Here's `nm -D --demangle libsubmit.so`:

```
...
0000000000000e0e T Submit_test()
...
```

How should I compile that code?

Comment: Have you included the header file of the library?

Comment: Also have a look at this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/45135/why-does-the-order-in-which-libraries-are-linked-sometimes-cause-errors-in-gcc

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is probably a dup of [how-to-know-if-one-shared-library-depends-on-another-shared-library-or-not](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40739799/how-to-know-if-one-shared-library-depends-on-another-shared-library-or-not)

TLDR is that you should put linked libs after object/source files.

Comment: I moved -lsubmit to the end and it indeed solved the issue